# How can I make <Link> to stop appending external link to localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am calling an api with a {url} key in the array, but when I try usng  I get something like this

```js
http://localhost:3002/https://techcrunch.com/2021/03/29/the-station-breaking-down-tusimples-s-1/
```

I can see that it is adding the external link to my localhost, how can I change this to behave normally?

Comment: are u using Link component from react router ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `<a>` element if you want to navigate outside of the React Router.

`<Link>` is for internal links.

See also [this bug report](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1147) with the conclusion:

> Let's re-open this until we can add some notes to the docs about using external links and add a warning for URLs with anything more than just a path in `<Link>`.